# Setting a default filter to a table in React

Tags: reactjs

in my current project I have been populating a table using an API, but by default displaying all records, then using a dropdown filter to further filter the results.  I have recently been asked if the dataset could be filter to only show the items that are "Active" but default, but be able to use the dropdown filter to show, Active, Inactive, or All results. I have tried a couple things to filter the dataset by default, but it still displays all records. Or, I can filter the dataset, but but dropdown filter no longer worked. what am I doing wrong?  How can I set the filter to active by default, but still be changeable??

**Dropdown Filter**

```
// Status To Filter By
const status = [
  {id: 1, label: '...', value: ''}, 
  {id: 2, label: 'Active', value: 0}, 
  {id: 3, label: 'Inactive', value: 1},
];

<DropdownFltr
   options={status}
   prompt='Status...'
   onChange={handleFilterValue1}
   value={selectedValue1}
/>
```

**Filter Handler**

```
const handleFilterValue1 = e => { 
  setSelectedValue1(e.target.value);
  const filterVal = (e.target.value).toString().toLowerCase();
  setFilter1Fn({
      fn: items => {
          if (filterVal === '')
            // { return items; } // returns all items without filtering
            
            { return items.filter(x => 
                 x.isActive.includes('0')
            ); }  // this did not work, still returns all results (0 = active)

          else
            { return items.filter(x =>
                x.isActive.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterVal)
            ); }
      }
  });
};


// Dataset Passed to Table
    const dataFilteredAndSorted = () => {
        return tableData(filter1Fn.fn(searchFn.fn(tableData)), getComparator(order, orderBy));
```

**Example API Response**

```
[
{"id":1, "name":"Dept Name 1","description":"Department 1","isActive":0},
{"id":2, "name":"Dept Name 2","description":"Department 2","isActive":1},
{"id":3, "name":"Dept Name 3","description":"Department 3","isActive":0},
{"id":4, "name":"Dept Name 4","description":"Department 4","isActive":1},
{"id":5, "name":"Dept Name 5","description":"Department 5","isActive":0},
{"id":6, "name":"Dept Name 6","description":"Department 6","isActive":1},
]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share some sample values for `items` to illustrate the structure of that data

Comment: @motto updated with example api data

Answer (score 0):

Give selectedValue1 a default (initial) value of Active. Put setFilterFn(....) in a separate function with filterVal as a parameter:

```
const filterTable = (filterVal) => {
  setFilter1Fn({
      fn: items => {
          if (filterVal === '')
            // { return items; } // returns all items without filtering
            
            { return items.filter(x => 
                 x.isActive.includes('0')
            ); }  // this did not work, still returns all results (0 = active)

          else
            { return items.filter(x =>
                x.isActive.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterVal)
            ); }
      }
  });
}
```

and call it in your component with selectedValue1 as a parameter:

```
filterTable(selectedValue1)
```

Comment: I must have done something wrong because all I got was errors